# IBAction is causing app to crash. Not giving a reason

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a subclass of `UIView` called `ToolbarView`. I created it's interface through the interface builder. It consists of 3 `UIButtons`. The center button is connected to a `IBAction` while the other two buttons are simply connected as `IBOutlets`. Here's the relevant code:

ToolbarView.m:

```
@implementation ToolbarView
@synthesize homeButton, otherButton, delegate; 

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ToolbarView" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];
    }
    return self;
}
```

ToolbarView.h:

```
@interface ToolbarView : UIView

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton* homeButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton* otherButton;

@property (weak, nonatomic) id delegate; 

- (IBAction)launchCamera:(id)sender;

@end
```

And here is the xib, and its connections:

### [image]

[image]

Everytime I touch the camera button, the app crashes, and the console only writes (lldb), and nothing more. Anyone know where I am going wrong?

update: here's the backtrace:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0xbf136, 0x00000001025d7fcb libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 11, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x18)
    frame #0: 0x00000001025d7fcb libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 11
    frame #1: 0x0000000101172f06 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 80
    frame #2: 0x0000000101172eb4 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 17
    frame #3: 0x000000010124f880 UIKit`-[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 203
    frame #4: 0x000000010124edc0 UIKit`-[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 530
    frame #5: 0x00000001011a9d05 UIKit`-[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 701
    frame #6: 0x00000001011aa6e4 UIKit`-[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 925
    frame #7: 0x000000010118229a UIKit`-[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 211
    frame #8: 0x000000010116faed UIKit`_UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 9579
    frame #9: 0x00000001027f4d21 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    frame #10: 0x00000001027f45f2 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 242
    frame #11: 0x000000010281046f CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 767
    frame #12: 0x000000010280fd83 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    frame #13: 0x00000001045bdf04 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 161
    frame #14: 0x0000000101171e33 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1010
  * frame #15: 0x00000001000025e3 Eventfeed`main(argc=1, argv=0x00007fff5fbfecd0) + 115 at main.m:16
```

Comment: When you're at the (lldb) prompt, type "bt".  The stack trace might be useful.  Also, code for the launchCamera: method might be useful.

Comment: does - (IBAction)launchCamera:(id)sender have an implementation?

Comment: There's no code in launchCamera:, it's an empty function right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File’s Owner must be set to the instantiating controller’s class and the referencedView outlet must be bound to the actual view you need. Do confirm once.

Comment: Can you expand on this? I feel this is where my error is occuring. Is the instantiating controller the view controller that is going to be initializing the view and using it. And what exactly do you mean when you say "the referencedView outlet must be bound to the actual view you need"?

Comment: Yes you are right. And you can set the view controller on the right hand side property window. Also under outlet the referenced view property should be control clicked dragged to the view.

Comment: Just gave this a shot and it worked. This was very useful to know for whenever I make xib-based views in the future. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Following ways to get to know about more details about the crash or fix it:

1. Use "bt" as Back Trace in console after crash for more details about the crash.
2. Check View Class is linked with the XIB.
3. Enabled `NSZombieEnabled` and then check.
4. Remove camera `IBAction` create again.
5. `Add Exception Breakpoint` and then check.

Answer (score 0):

First, Add exception breakpoint

[image: Breakpoint]

Second, try to review implementation of

`- (IBAction)launchCamera:(id)sender;`

It's more likely you'll find solution on this point. But if not, try to remove

> ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

And clean your project (Cmd + Shift + K)